# Castle Windsor Registration of Interface and Abstract Implementations

Tags: castle-windsor

I am trying to work out how to auto register implementations of an generic abstract class or interface. Here are my classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractValidator<T> : IValidator<T>
{
   public void Validate(T)
   {
      ...
   }
}

public class CustomerValidator:AbstractValidator<Customer>
{
  ...
}
```

I am trying the following:

```
_container = new WindsorContainer();
_container.Register(
    AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<ValidationPatterns>()
         .BasedOn<IValidator>()
         .WithService.Base()
    }));

IValidator<Customer> val = _container.Resolve<IValidator<Customer>>();
```

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: And are you getting an error?  Is this not working?

Comment: Yeah was not working, but answer below resolved it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close.
Should be `BasedOn(typeof(IValidator<>))` that is the generic open type.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. Very cool to be able to auto register all services like this. Hope this post will help others. Cheers